# How does the path environment variable work?

Tags: variables, path, system

I know how to add values to the path variable, so my question is not *how* to use it.

Rather, I want to know how it works under the hood. When you type in the name of a program to execute, how does the system make use of PATH to find the matching program? How does it know when it finds a match?

Comment: It checks whether the file exists.

Comment: On Windows, the shell looks in the current directory for the executable file. If it finds it, it runs it. Then, it looks in the directories of the `PATH` variable until it finds a directory that contains the executable. It is a bit more complicated when you start applying the extensions in `PATHEXT`.

Comment: And while it's doing what @Liturgist describes, it executes the first match it finds and then stops searching.

Answer (score 3):

for example...
when you set c:\python27\ into your environment path...
and you goto cmd, you are at c:\ and you type python
cmd knows to check the environment path which it will find c:\python27\ among others. then it looks for the command in each path listed in your environment paths
then executes the command if it finds it

simply the env path tells where to look for the command if it is not in the current directory